# Intuitive explanation of 'Normal' integral

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

For $f$ given as (standard normal density)
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{2}}},
\end{equation}
the follwing holds
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_a^\infty  {xf(x)dx}  = f(a).
\end{equation}
This result isn't hard to derive. However, I'm having a difficulty to *intuitively* understand why *'expected' value of* $X\sim N(0,1)$ *over a region is equal to the density at the lower bound*. I know it isn't a true expected value but still. Why a result of this integral is equal to $f(a)$?

Comment: $f$ satisfies $f'(x)=-xf(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, therefore $\int_t^\infty xf(x)\,dx=f(t)$.

Comment: @Gae.S. You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @angryavian Should I? Because I don't know if this is what the author is asking for.

Comment: @Gae.S. You can, I like your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick is that $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ satisfies the differential equation $f'(x)=-xf(x)$ and its limit as $x\to\infty$ is $0$ (this condition is already a consequence of being a solution of the differential equation, but there's no harm in mentioning it). Therefore $\int_x^\infty tf(t)\,dt=f(x)$.